# Logical errors in a discussion of integration methods

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

My niece Alexa and her friend Jamie had the following conversation with their teacher:

> Alexa: This integration question stumps me. Can you offer me a hint?
>
> Teacher: This integration question can be solved using either
> integration by parts or integration by substitution.
>
> Jamie: I'm aware that integration by substitution can be used to
> answer this question. I just did it myself yesterday.
>
> Alexa: Now I get it! That suggests my initial strategy of integration
> by parts was erroneous! No wonder I couldn't answer the question.
>
> Teacher: This is a difficult question to answer. Whatever method you
> choose, you will need at least eight steps to complete your task.
>
> Alexa: Excellent! I worked in ten steps. That means I'm correct.

Based on the conversation, these logical errors have occurred:

**Affirming a disjunct**: When Jamie said, "I'm aware that integration by substitution can be used to answer this question," she was making a claim about a disjunction (either integration by parts or integration by substitution can be used). Alexa then made the mistake of assuming that her initial strategy of integration by parts was wrong, based on Jamie's claim about integration by substitution being a valid method. This is an example of affirming a disjunct, which is a logical fallacy where one assumes that one option in a disjunction is true and concludes that the other option must be false.

**Using a specific example to prove a universal statement**: When Alexa claimed that her working in ten steps meant that she was correct, she was making the mistake of using a specific example (her own solution) to prove a universal statement (that any correct solution would require at least eight steps). Just because Alexa's solution happened to be correct and required ten steps does not mean that any correct solution would also require ten steps.

There do not appear to be any instances of **inverse error**, **converse error**, or **mislabelling of elements** in the conversation.

Is my analysis correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re correct that those two lines of reasoning are erroneous, but the second error is actually a converse error. That is, if a student answers correctly, then it takes more than eight lines, but that doesn’t mean that if a student takes more than eight lines, then the student answers correctly. In a more informal/inductive sense, Alexa also assumes that Jamie’s answer is correct based off of her testimony, which without further evidence is not a guarantee that she really used integration by parts to get the right answer.